# How to use LazyColumn

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose-lazy-column

I have a Market model, inside the Market there is a list of Offers, and inside the Offers there is a list of Attributes, and in the Attributes list there are several name and value variables. I need to use the variables inside this Attributes list. I've used View Model and Jetpack Compose, so I don't want to use Lazy Column. How can I extract the Attributes list?

```java
{
    val bigMarket = remember { mutableStateListOf<BigMarketData>() }

    LaunchedEffect(bigMarketVM) {
        bigMarketVM.marketLiveData.asFlow().collect { marketItem ->
            marketItem?.let { it1 -> bigMarket.add(it1) }
        }
    }
    
    LazyColumn {
        itemsIndexed(
            items = bigMarket,
            key = { _, item -> item.toString() }
        ) { _, item ->
            for (i in 0 until bigMarket[0].offers.size) {
                loadCompose(item = bigMarket[i].offers[i].attributes[i])
            }
        }
    }
}
```